# One time SSH password

Tags: ssh

Every time, when I logging to a server via ssh. It asks me to input password. I don't want to input password every logging. 
Is there any ways to store my password in the server?

Note: I'm not used the "root" user. Also no public-key.

Comment: Are SSH key-pairs not possible? They are a very widely used solution to this scenario.

Comment: Yes, They are not possible in this case, because the customer disallow that.